# Import and create a Smart Folder from a list

Tags: deepsecurity

Hello good Sirs and Mams,

Im fairly new to the whole DSM administration and have a few questions.
The one that would help me out the most is regarding Smart Folders and automatically populate them.
Ive read through the API documentation and it seems like there is no function for Smart Folder creation.

What im trying to do is to import a list from a *.csv file (or directly from AD group) to a Smart Folder view in DSM, how do i achieve this ?
I got the file populated but there i cant get further. Any pointers and advice welcome.

https://automation.deepsecurity.trendmicro.com/article/11_2/api-reference?platform=on-premise#operation/createComputerGroup

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Smart Folders are similar to Advanced Save Searches".  You can create a Smart Folder with conditions.  The API documentation is here (for Deep Security Manager 11.2): https://automation.deepsecurity.trendmicro.com/legacy-rest/11_2/index.html?env=onprem#create_smart_folder

If you're trying to use Computer Groups, instead of Smart Folders, you would have to create the Computer Group using the API, and then modify each Computer object, setting the GroupID field: https://automation.deepsecurity.trendmicro.com/article/11_2/api-reference?platform=on-premise#operation/modifyComputer

Alternatively, if it's Active Directory, you can configure Deep Security to automatically synchronize with Active Directory, which will handle the folder structure for you. 
 See https://help.deepsecurity.trendmicro.com/12_0/on-premise/Add-Computers/ug-add-activedirectory.html for more information.

Nick Willan

Trend Micro

Comment: Thank you kind sir, this was exactly what i was trying to find!

Comment: However, if i understand the smart-folder documentation above it seems i can not create a smart folder based on a specific AD-GROUP. Thats why im trying to find how i can import a list instead and import it into a smart folder - perhaps its stated and i will have read in more depth and see if its mentioned somewhere - else i will return :)

Thanks again for quick response!

Comment: So after 5-6 hours of reading up i realize this is out of my scope. The script required to do this is to advanced. I guess i could do it in PS with ps -> ad -> csv -> ps and then run a invoke-webrequest -> DS, but i can barley make a "hello world" ^^. 

Thanks my man, i will pass this along to someone with more expertise then me.